# Joomla! Virtuemart - Option to Go To Next Product to be Edited

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

Is there a Virtuemart extension that makes it possible to go to the next product you want to edit so you do not need to go back to product overview page to pick the next one? Going through many products to be edited it would be great to quickly flick through them, but that seems to be impossible now. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My kingdom for such a tool, but alas, to my knowledge there is no such tool.  There IS, however, a workaround that I use - from the product page, I just right-click the link to edit it and choose "Open in New Window" and close the window when I'm done.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the URL in browser bar, take the id of product you are currently editing adding +1 to the id, to avoid opening more pages.

Remember to do this after saving, obviously

http://yourserver.com/ administrator/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=product&task=edit&virtuemart_product_id[]=3615

and then you make

http://yourserver.com/ administrator/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=product&task=edit&virtuemart_product_id[]=3616

and so on